# Android - Unable to use variable during life transitions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to use a global variable(which is an object) during the stages of the activity (onPause, onRestart, onDestroy, etc.) but I think I don't have access to it.

How can I solve this ? Here is an example of what I mean.

Edit: Updated example.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private X myObject = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       myObject = new X();
    }

    @Override
     protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        myObject.doSomething();
    }
}


public class X {
  public X() {}
  public void doSomething(){}
}
```

This is the kind of error I was talking about

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I am using the same myObject variable I have initialized in the method onCreate in several parts of the code and works flawlessly. So that isn't the problem.

Last edit: Looks like it was some bug with the Android Studio IDE. I had to make a new project , copy - paste the exactly same code I had and now it works. Thanks for the answers anyway.

Comment: you are missing variable type

Comment: In `onCreate` method you are declaring a new variable, not assigning value to the global one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ***MyObject*** myObject;

    @Override
     protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        myObject.doSomething();
    }
}
```

variable should have a type. Define variable type. you can access it in life cycle methods.

Comment: sorry it was a typo and a bad example. this is not the real code. It's only a brief concept of my issue.

Comment: it may be either class or method of myobject class doesn't have access to be called on other class or outside class.